# How to write Kubernetes annotations to the underlying YAML files?

Tags: kubernetes, annotations, yaml, containers, kubectl

I am looking to apply existing annotations on a Kubernetes resource to the underlying YAML configuration files. For example, this command will successfully find all pods with a label of "app=helloworld" or "app=testapp" and annotate them with "xyz=test_anno":

`kubectl annotate pods -l 'app in (helloworld, testapp)' xyz=test_anno`

However, this only applies the annotations to the running pods and doesn't change the YAML files. How do I force those changes to the YAML files so they're permanent, either after the fact or as part of `kubectl annotate` to start with?

Comment: Your YAML files and Kubernetes resources aren't linked in any way, so you can't use kubectl to change your files. You could look into kustomize to add default annotations, or simply get the YAML files from your deployed pods (e.g. `kubectl get pods -o yaml` or `kubectl get deployment -o yaml`).

Comment: As char said, you can'tuse kubectl to change your yaml files. If you are using deployment, you can edit the deployment file using `kubectl edit deployment xyz` and add the annotation you want. Please clarify where is your yaml files, and how you are work with them.

Comment: I'd edit the YAML files, commit them to source control, and `kubectl apply` them.  That's a workflow where you're always starting from the YAML and making the cluster reflect it, rather than modifying the cluster and trying to make your source code match it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `kubectl patch` command with a little tricks

```
kubectl patch $(k get po -l 'app in (helloworld, testapp)') -p '{"metadata":{"annotations":{"xyz":"test_anno"}}}'
```